# I want when the user click on product url to change mean => example.dev/shop/5615156/LG-Controller slug/productName

Tags: laravel, routes, where-clause, laravel-5.8

I want www.example.com/shop/slug/productname

I have a error :

```
     Missing required parameters for [Route: shop.show] [URI: 
     shop/{slug}/{productName}]. (0)
```

my route for each product

```
                {{ route('shop.show',[$product->slug,$product->name]) }}
```

and is my shopcontroller

```
       public function show($slug,$productName)
       {
       $productslug = Product::where('slug',$slug)->firstOrFail();
      $productname = Product::where('name',$productName)->firstOrFail();
       $mightAlsoLike = Product::where('slug', '!=' ,$slug)- 
          >MightAlsoLike()->get();

         return view('front.product')
               ->with('product', $productname)
              ->with('product', $productslug)
               ->with( 'mightAlsoLike', $mightAlsoLike);
            }
```

and is my web.php :

```
    Route::get('/shop/{slug}/{productName}', 'ShopController@show')->name('shop.show');
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to pass key in case of multiple route parameters.

```
Route::get('/shop/{slug}/{productName}', 'ShopController@show')->name('shop.show');
```

And use route like this:

```
{{ route('shop.show',['slug'=>$product->slug,'productName'=>$product->name]) }}
```